# stbi_load Method isn't accepting my parameters

Tags: java, lwjgl, stb-image

```
bi = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
width = bi.getWidth();
height = bi.getHeight();
            
ByteBuffer data = stbi_load("/sprites/" + filename, width, height, 0, 0);
```

For some reason, `stbi_load` isn't accepting the second, third, and fourth parameters in the method, even though they're all valid integers. It gives the following error

```
The method stbi_load(ByteBuffer, IntBuffer, IntBuffer, IntBuffer, int) in the type STBImage is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int, int).
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Any answers are appreciated

Comment: if I remember right you must use the file system path and not the claspath

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show the `stbi_load` method signature.

Maybe it expects arguments of types [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [IntBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html), not of types `String` and `int` as you provided.

Comment: The method stbi_load(ByteBuffer, IntBuffer, IntBuffer, IntBuffer, int) in the type STBImage is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int, int). Thats the method signature, so ye it does expect the types u mentioned above, but why is it asking for those instead of the regular string and ints?

Comment: Because the [STBImage class](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/stb/STBImage.html) was designed that way.